# .Clipped() not working on Pickers SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, datepicker, swiftui, picker

I need to create a view that has 2 `Pickers` and 2 `DatePickers`.

In order to avoid having them overlapping each other, I used `.clipped()`. However, this is not working.

I can successfully resize the `pickers`, but I cannot limit the "selection area" to their `frame` size.

Here is my code:

```
VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Picker(selection: self.$dayTypeSelectedIndex, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< self.dayTypes.count, id: \.self) {
                Text(self.dayTypes[$0])
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .labelsHidden()
        .clipped()
        
        Spacer()
        
        Group {
            DatePicker("", selection: self.$dateIntervalStart, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .labelsHidden()
                .colorInvert()
                .colorMultiply(Color.black)
                .frame(maxHeight: 50)
                .clipped()
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("às")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            
            Spacer()
            
            DatePicker("", selection: self.$dateIntervalEnd, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .labelsHidden()
                .colorInvert()
                .colorMultiply(Color.black)
                .frame(maxHeight: 50)
                .clipped()
        }
        
        Spacer()
        
        HStack {
            Picker(selection: self.$tripNotificationDelta, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0...60, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0 < 10 ? "0\($0)" : "\($0)")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            }
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(maxWidth: 50, maxHeight: 50)
            .clipped()

            Text("mins before trip")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using XCode 12. Plus, this interface is being built for devices not running iOS 14.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I figured it out. Just put `.compositingGroup()` before `.clipped()`. Something like this:

```
            DatePicker("", selection: self.$dateIntervalEnd, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            .labelsHidden()
            .colorInvert()
            .colorMultiply(Color.black)
            .frame(maxHeight: 50)
            .compositingGroup()
            .clipped()
```

Comment: This fix also just worked for me for Image cropping in iOS 14

Comment: Great finding. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687986?answerId=685001022#685001022)

Adding this simple extension solves the problem with overlapping scroll areas. You don't need to add `.compositingGroup()` and `.clipped()`

```
extension UIPickerView {
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)
}
}
```